# iis 7 dynamic redirects for .html files and directories

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7, httphandler, httpmodule

I've implemented an `httpmodule` to manage 301 redirects in the database. It does a simple (cached) db lookup to find any matching entries and if it finds any it performs a redirect.

It works wonderfully for `.aspx` files and other .Net related extensions.

However, for paths ending in `.html` or `/` I'm having a more difficult time. I can add a handler for such files as follows:

```
<add name="SubDirectory" path="*/*/" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
  <add name="ForDirectory" path="*/" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
  <add name="SubHTML" path="*/*.html" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
  <add name="ForHTML" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
```

but I've run into two issues:

1. If there is a directory with a default document (default.aspx) the
   `ForDirectory` handler breaks it.
2. If anything is requested on these
   paths that doesn't have a redirect and doesn't exist, the server
   returns an error rather than a 404: `Failed to Execute URL`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Switching IIS to integrated rather than classic mode was/is the solution. No handlers are needed, either.